# 正しいタグについて

Tags: サポート, タグ

[スマホでのCSSの影響、表示確認の方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/56410/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AEcss%E3%81%AE%E5%BD%B1%E9%9F%BF-%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

上記のような質問をしたのですが、CSSのコードや書き方の質問ではありません。
CSSのタグが最適ではないとは思いつつ選択した次第なのですが、何か適したタグがあればご教授下さい。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

今回の場合、Web デザインの「テスト」方法に関する質問なので、[テスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%86%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88)というタグはいかがでしょうか？

「Web デザイン」など、最適なタグがあれば良いのですが、残念ながら存在しないため、その代替として[css](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)タグを付けておいても構わないと思います。

また、スタック・オーバーフローには[デザイン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%87%e3%82%b6%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3)タグがありますが、これはソフトウェア設計に関する質問という意味合いが強いようなので、今回の質問では使えないかもしれません。